# stringbuilder not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, stringbuilder

**.cs**

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.Append("<script language='javascript'>($('#phnoe').show();)</script>");
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "chp", str.ToString(), true);
    }
```

**.aspx**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ch_p" Text="phone" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
        oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"/>
</div><div id="p" style="float:left;"><asp:TextBox style="float: left;" runat="server" id="phnoe" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox></div></div><br />
```

output - on checkedchanged //]]> is appearing on top of the page

Answer (score 2):

You should change this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "chp", str.ToString(), true);
```

to

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "chp", str.ToString(), false);
```

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript add javascript code, when all Dom Content is rendered on Page.

As you are already adding script tag in your string builder, so there is no need to make addScriptTag parameter to true.

But in your aspx markup you made the textbox visible="false".

```
<asp:TextBox style="float: left;" runat="server" id="phnoe" Visible="false">
</asp:TextBox>
```

so it will not render, and your script will not able to display it.

You should change in your mark up like

```
<asp:TextBox style="float: left;" runat="server" id="phnoe" style="display:none;">
</asp:TextBox>
```

So, It can render on web, but it will not display. as we set its display to none.

And If you just want to show it on checkbox check, There is no need to make it server side. you can easily do it with jquery.

So your markup should

```
<div>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="ch_p" Text="phone" runat="server"  />
</div>
<div id="p" style="float:left;">
    <asp:TextBox style="float: left;" runat="server" id="phnoe" style="display:none">
    </asp:TextBox>
</div></div><br />
```

Make a Javascript code like using jquery

```
$(function(){
      $('[ID$=ch_p]').on("click",function(){
           if(this.checked)
               $('[ID$=phnoe]').show();
           else 
               $('[ID$=phnoe]').hide();
      });
});
```

It will solve your issue.

Hope It will help you.